# Adding a list into another list in python

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to make a loop that keeps adding list into another list.

```
list1 = [[1], [2], [3], [4]]
list2 = []

while True:
    list2.insert(len(list2), int(input("Here: ")))
    list1.insert(len(list1), list2)
    print(list1)
    list2.clear()
```

But then it gives me this:

```
Here: 10
[[1], [2], [3], [4], [10]]
Here: 20
[[1], [2], [3], [4], [20], [20]]
Here: 30
[[1], [2], [3], [4], [30], [30], [30]]
Here:
```

But I want:

```
Here: 10
[[1], [2], [3], [4], [10]]
Here: 20
[[1], [2], [3], [4], [10], [20]]
Here: 30
[[1], [2], [3], [4], [10], [20], [30]]
Here:
```

I am still at a basic level...

Comment: `list1.insert(len(list1), list2)` adds the same object to `list1` inside the loop. You need to create a new object inside the loop instead. Just move the `list2 = []` inside the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`list1.insert(len(list1), list2)` adds the same object to `list1` inside the loop. You need to create a new object inside the loop instead. Just move the `list2 = []` inside the loop

*[copied from [rdas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2947378/rdas)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62997012/adding-a-list-into-another-list-in-python/62997118#comment111402418_62997012)]*

Answer (score 0):

`list1.append([int(input("Here: "))])`

If you use `list.append()`, it always adds to the end of the `list` which is generally what you do here in both cases.

The creation of a second list is unnecessary as the comments suggest. You can create a list of list directly by placing your `input()` into `[]`-braces.